# Why isn't my Thread.sleep() working as intended?

Tags: java, sleep

My code currently looks like this, and I want to delay the process AFTER the release code takes place, but before the game starting, but currently it looks as if the release code doesn't occur at all. It looks as if after the delay, the start happens immediately after, which I don't want. If anyone can help, thanks.

This is my code.

```java
startButton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // Press
        startButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240, 240));
        startButton.setIcon(startButtonHover);
        FRAME.pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // Release
        // NOT TRIGGERING AT ALL
        startButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(256, 256));
        startButton.setIcon(startButtonImage);
        FRAME.pack();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(400);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        // Game Start
        FRAME.remove(menuPanel);
        FRAME.revalidate();
        FRAME.repaint();

    }

});
```

Comment: Because seing is single threaded (and not thread safe), you can’t block the event dispatching thread, otherwise ui can’t be updated. Use a swing Timer instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost all UI systems, and swing (which is what you are using here) is one of them, has this concept called the Event Dispatcher Thread, or EDT.

The EDT has a bunch of properties:

- There is only one such thread.
- Any interaction with the UI (as in, `jLabel.setText("Hello")`, removing or adding widgets, changing the colour of something, and so on) **must** be done from the EDT. If you do it from any other thread, weird things will happen.
- All event handlers (so, your on mouse click code and such) runs inside the EDT.
- **You must never block the EDT**. The EDT is the thread that is taking caring of ensuring your program repaints itself if the user drags another window across your app's window (the OS doesn't remember those pixels! The OS just asks the app to redraw itself; sometimes the mouse pointer isn't a hardware sprite and leaves a 'trail' in its wake). The EDT is also the thread that is taking care of e.g. if the user presses a button but doesn't let go, that the button is re-painted in a 'it is now pressed down' look.

Ever seen a napp crash such that even pressing buttons doesn't do anything, or the thing just becomes a dull grey colour once you hide it and re-show it and even drag any window across it?

That'd be an app that violated that rule.

Here you are sleeping in the EDT. **This is forbidden**.

Blocking acts:

- Talking to a DB
- Opening a file
- Interacting with anything on the network
- Waiting for a thread.
- A `synchronized` anything.
- `Thread.sleep`
- and much, much more. Anything that would cause the thread to sleep as it cannot continue until some event occurs (disk ready with bytes, some time passes, a lock becomes free, and so on).

The solution is not to sleep 400 millisec and then act. The solution is instead to create a new thread which waits 400 milliseconds, and which then injects the code to remove, revalidate, and repaint back into the EDT (after all, that thread is not the EDT, so you can wait 400 millis in it, but you cannot act on the UI, because you must only do that from the EDT).

This is annoying, but somewhat common, so swing has a thing for it: [`SwingTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: *"The solution is instead to create a new thread which waits 400 milliseconds, and which then injects the code to remove"* - Except Swing is not thread safe either, and you shouldn't modify the state the UI relies on from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. While you've mentioned a Swing `Timer`, "suggesting" the use of a `Thread` could lead to misunderstandings - I'm just staying

Comment: For actual background processing, I prefer `SwingWorker` over `Timer`. `Timer` still runs on the EDT, whereas most of `SwingWorker` runs in a different thread. Only the `process` and `done` methods run on the EDT.

Comment: @MadProgrammer You really need to read sentences until you hit a full stop before writing a comment. That very line you quote explicitly spells out you have to inject the UI-changing code __into the EDT__. You want me to write it in bold or something?

Comment: @rzwitserloot I did read it, several times, until I understood you intent, which is why it's a comment and not a downvote. You should read my comment in full, as I was trying to say that it would be easily mis-understood by a novice developer, I'm just saying - remember, the meaning of communication is determined by the receiver. If you prefer, I'll just drop a downvote next time and walk away